# How to unit test a non-public method of a class in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode5

I have defined a function in a category extension of my class.

Although this function is not a public API, it is a important function and i want to be able to unit test this function.

In the unit test, as expected, XCode complaints the function is not declared.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: There's no such thing as a private method in Objective-C -- you can always get at it.  It's just that some have better bodyguards than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should only test interfaces, so maybe the method should actually be public. If you still want the method to be private and write a unit test for it, you can redeclare the method in a category:

Just before your test class add:

```
@interface ClassUnderTest (IReallyWantToTestPrivateMethodsEvenThoughIShouldnt)
    - (void)thePrivateMethodToBeTested;
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't test private methods.  Test the public methods that use the private method.  And if the private method doesn't work, the test for the public method that uses it should fail. How a method works (and what private method it calls) is a trivial implementation detail that your test should not be concerned about.  Test the result, not how it achieves that result.

See this thread for more about why: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods (They talk about Java, but the principle applies to any language).

Answer (score 1):

Make that function public but put the declaration within #ifdef DEBUG so that it is public only when testing. The released code won't have it as public.